# jQuery UI Accordion Locking Certain Elements

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion, locked

I have a jQuery UI Accordion set up on my page with multiple h3 items.

For some reason, after I select, say, one in the middle, it locks some of the other elements. There doesn't seem to be a pattern as to which are locked out.

When I hover over them, I don't even seem to have the option to action-click them.

Here's the code for it.

```
$( "#catalog" ).accordion({
autoHeight : false,
disabled : false});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

**EDIT**
Here's the answer to fixing this issue:

```
$("#catalog h3").click(function(event){event.stopPropagation();});
```

Comment: Please give your solution as an answer to your question and mark it solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stopPropagation on your h3s, I'm guessing that your HTML has an error in it, as in, you have forgotten to close out a tag, or have nested your h3s.  Run your HTML through the validator and make sure you don't have any orphan elements, or haven't forgotton to close out any tags.

I highly recommend doing this to make sure your markup is correct, just in case you're patching an html error with a JS hack.